# Understanding a proof of the Wedderburn theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields

**Wedderburn theorem:** Every finite division ring is a field.

The following proof seem easier than other which I manage to understand the theorem. Although some logic(highlighted ones) still seems unclear to me.

**proof:** Let $D$ be a finite division ring with center $Z$. Suppose $Z$ has $q$ element and $D$ has $q^n$ elements. We claim that $D=Z$ and $n=1$. Since, $D^{\times}=D-\{0\}$ is multiplicative group. we split up the multiplicative group $D^{\times}$ into its conjugate classes. Each element of $Z$ forms a conjugate class by itself. Suppose, there are classes $C_1,\cdots,C_k$ in addition each containing more than one element. We know that conjugate class $C$ consists of $\frac{q^n-1}{q^r-1}$ elements where $r|n$.

> "conjugate class $C$ consists of $\frac{q^n-1}{q^r-1}$ elements where $r|n$", I didn't recognize or manage this result.

So corresponding to each class $C_i$ there is a factor $r_i$ of $n$ such that $C_i$ consists of $\frac{q^n-1}{q^{r_i}-1}$ elements and $r_i<n$. Hence, $$D^{\times}=\cup_{x\in Z^{\times}}[x]\bigcup \cup_{x\notin Z^{\times}}[x]\implies O(D^{\times})=O(Z^{\times})+\sum_{x\notin Z^{\times}}|C_i|\implies q^n-1=q-1+\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{q^n-1}{q^{r_i}-1}$$
Now, the nth cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n$ is a factor of both the polynomial $X^n-1$ and $\frac{X^n-1}{X^{r_i}-1}$.

> The nth cyclotomic polynomial, for any positive integer $n$, is the unique irreducible polynomial with integer coefficients that is a divisor of $x^{n}-1$ and is not a divisor of $x^{k}-1$ for any $k < n$. but here it say also for $\frac{X^n-1}{X^{r_i}-1}$, which I couldn't understand.

Let $a=\Phi_n(q)$ then $a$ divides $q^n-1$ and $\frac{q^n-1}{q^{r_i}-1}$. Hence, $a|q-1$. If $n>1$ then for every primitive nth root of unity $\xi$ in the field of complex numbers $\mathbb C$. we have $|q-\xi|>|q-1|$ hence $|a|=\prod |q-\xi|>q-1$.

> I couldn't manage to understand $|a|=\prod |q-\xi|>q-1$. Why the product come in?

And hence $a$ can't be a factor of $q-1$. It follows that there are no classes $C_i$ containing more than one element. Hence, $n=1$ and $D=Z$.

---

I couldn't manage to understand the in-between logic I highlight above.

To be honest I couldn't manage to understand this theorem intuitively, like a connected logics to write the proof by own (after understanding once). It will be great help if anyone enlighten me the intuition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will enumerate your questions by 1,2,3.

1. This is because of the orbit-stabilizer theorem. Here, $D^\times$ acts on itself by conjugation. The orbits are the conjugacy classes (by their very definition). The stabilizers are the centralizers (by their very definition). Each centralizer, including $0$, is a vector space over the center $Z$, therefore has $q^r$ elements with some $r$. The orbit-stabilizer theorem now implies that the orbit has $(q^n - 1)/(q^r - 1)$ elements. Hence, $q^r - 1 \mid q^n - 1$, and [this implies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7473) $r \mid n$.
2. We have the factorization $X^n - 1 = \prod_{\large d \mid n} \Phi_d$, and then also $X^{r_i} - 1 = \prod_{\large d \mid r_i} \Phi_d$. Thus, $(X^n - 1)/(X^{r_i} - 1) = \prod_{\large d \mid n, ~ d \not\mid r_i} \Phi_d$, and $\Phi_n$ divides $(X^n - 1)/(X^{r_i}-1)$.
3. The polynomial $\Phi_n$ factors as $\prod_{\zeta} (X - \zeta)$, where $\zeta$ runs through all primitive $n$-th roots of unity. Substitute $X$ by $q$, then we get $a = \Phi_n(q) = \prod_{\zeta} (q-\zeta)$.

Let me mention that all of these questions are also answered by [Wikipedia's proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, @MartinBrandenburg. Can you help me with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4832155/equivalence-conditions-for-semisimple-ring) one?

Answer (score 1):

> "conjugate class $C$ consists of $\frac{q^n-1}{q^r-1}$ elements where $r \mid n$"

Let $a\in C_1$ and $\mathrm{Fix}(a)$ is the elements fixing it under conjugation (admitting $0$):
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{Fix}(a)=\{x\in D:\ ax=xa\}.
\end{equation*}
It is easy to check $\mathrm{Fix}(a)$ is a subring of $D$, and is a division ring:
$0,1\in D$, closeness under addition, multiplication, negative elemnts are easy to check, and as for inverse of non-zero members,
\begin{equation*}
xa=ax\implies xax^{-1}=a\implies ax^{-1}=x^{-1}a.
\end{equation*}
It is immediate that $D\supseteq Z$.
Recall every module over a division ring has a basis (though its weakened edition "every module over a field has a basis" is much more commonly used).
Therefore $\mathrm{Fix}(a)$ is a vector space over $Z$, and $D$ is a vector space over the division ring $C(a)$.
The first assertion shows that $\mathrm{Fix}(a)$ has $q^r$ elements where $r=\dim_Z \mathrm{Fix}(a)$.
Recall the transitivity of dimension:
\begin{equation*}
\dim_Z \mathrm{Fix}(a)\dim_{\mathrm{Fix}(a)}D=\dim_ZD\overset{\text{hypothesis}}{=}{r}.
\end{equation*}
Therefore ${\color{violet}{r \mid n}}$.
Since the multiplicative group $(D-\{0\},\cdot)$ acts on $C_1$ transitively and $\mathrm{Fix}(a)-\{0\}$ is the stablizer of $a\in C_1$, we infer \begin{equation*}
\text{card}(C_1)=\frac{\text{card(}D-{0})}{\text{card}(\mathrm{Fix}(a)-\{0\})}=\frac{q^n-1}{q^r-1},
\end{equation*}
where we have proved ${\color{violet}{r \mid n}}$.

> Now, the nth cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n$ is a factor of both the polynomial $X^n-1$ and $\frac{X^n-1}{X^{r_i}-1}$.

Since $\Phi_n$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, it is a prime element in the UFD $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Therefore
\begin{equation*}
(\text{In }\mathbb{Z}[x])\    \Phi_n(x) \mid \frac{X^n-1}{X^{r_i}-1}\cdot {X^{r_i}-1},\ \Phi_n(x)\nmid {X^{r_i}-1} \implies \Phi_n(x) \mid \frac{X^n-1}{X^{r_i}-1}.
\end{equation*}

> I couldn't manage to understand $|a|=\prod |q-\xi|>q-1$. Why the product come in?

\begin{equation}
{\color{violet}{q^n-1}}=q-1+{\color{violet}{\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{q^n-1}{q^{r_i}-1}}}
\end{equation}
All ${\color{violet}{\text{violet}}}$ terms are multiple of $\Phi_n(q)$ as we have proved. Then we should have $\Phi_n(q) \mid q-1$, which is absurd, since
\begin{equation*}
\Phi_n(x)=\prod_{\substack{1\le k\le n\\\gcd(k,n)=1}}(x-e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}),\ \ (\text{a well-known equivalent definition of $\Phi_n$})
\end{equation*}
and $|x-e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}|>|x|-|e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}|=x-1$.