# Need example of a finite noncommutative ring with inverses

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields

I'm trying to write some test cases for set of code, and I need an example of a finite ring (with identity) which is not commutative, but has inverses (for non-zero elements) and whose additive identity is distinct from its multiplicative identity.

The reason I need this is because I had some code to detect a finite field which was passing all my test cases, yet I was not checking whether the multiplication is commutative.   Having such a test case would make my code more robust.

My test for field is that the set be

1. a commutative ring with identity,
2. having distinct multiplicative and additive identities,
3. for which all non-zero elements have inverses

Comment: Actually, such an example does not exist because [any finite division ring is a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4835156/a-finite-division-ring-d-is-a-field).

Comment: I've tried to post it as an answer, I don't know why it is automatically converted to a comment.

Comment: Perhaps, Matteo, it doesn't have enough characters for the software to accept it as an answer. Try expanding on it a little, and then posting it. (You aren't under an answer ban, are you?)

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, I'll follow your advice (no, I'm not under an answer ban)

Comment: Hello Jim: with exceedingly few exceptions, rings in which multiplication is commutative are called *commutative* and not *Abelian*.  I realize this doesn't quite line up with what groups do.  Actually the adjective *abelian* is used for a [different condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_(ring_theory)#Rings_characterized_by_idempotents) in rings. At any rate, using *commutative* instead will help others with the same question find the solutions here.

Answer (score 5):

A ring is called a division ring if any non-zero element is invertible. A field is a commutative division ring.

So what you are asking for is a finite division ring which is not a field. Actually such an example does not exist beacuse [any finite division ring is a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4835156/a-finite-division-ring-d-is-a-field).

Comment: Great to know.  That means I don't need to check commutativity if the ring is finite.

Comment: The result that any finite division ring is a field is known as Wedderburn's little theorem.